Is there a way to use hubspot api to check if the crm contacts i am parsing through have an assigned tag?
I have an excel list of contacts that I am checking on hubspot, so far I have been able to use the hubspot crm contacts API to check if the contact exists, i want to add another feature that checks if they've been assigned a specific tag. for context, we created a custom property label, this label assigns tags to the contacts by using multiple checkboxes. my requirement is to check if they've been assigned a specific tag from those checkboxes, but I am having trouble retrieving this property.
I have tried the properties api, but haven't had any success. https://api.hubapi.com/properties/v1/contacts/properties/named/
